# Is there any Russian surname similar to Macorís?

Tags: транслитерация

This is the 1840s confirmation record of a Russian convert to Catholicism. The names of his parents back in Kamchatka, probably orally reported to the Spanish-speaking priest who wrote in the register book, are recognizably Russian except for the word that resembles *Macorís*.

I haven't been able to find any similar name or surname. Is it after all Russian?

[image: Confirmation record]

> Jose Bolcoff [Осип Волков]. Son of Jacobo Bolcoff [Яков Волков] and Ana **Macorís** [*?*]. Godfather Francisco Soria.

Comment: The most similar surname I can match is _Macarova_ (Макарова).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about Russian language and it won't help other Russian language learners.

Comment: Maybe some west-Ukrainian (polish?) surname? just remembering the Green Triangle

Comment: There is a very rare last name Макорий (Makoriy). As an a example, it's mentioned here: https://www.ronl.ru/referaty/raznoe/533957 Makoriy could be a variation of Makariy (Макарий). The latter is used more often as a first name rather than the last name.

Comment: @Vitaly spasibo -- that's a good match and makes me think that it could be a derived from a priestly name.